# How do I use Nagios to monitor a log file that generates a random ID

Tags: linux, bash, logging, monitoring, nagios

This the log file that I want to monitor:

```
/test/James-2018-11-16_15215125111115-16.15.41.111-appserver0.log
```

I want Nagios to read it this log file so I can monitor a specific string.

The issue is with **15215125111115** this is the random id that gets generated

Here is my script where the Nagios is checking for the **Logfile** path:

**Veriables:**

```
HOSTNAMEIP=$(/bin/hostname -i)
DATE=$(date +%F)
```

..

> CHECK=$(/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_logfiles/check_logfiles
>   --tag='failorder' --logfile=/test/james-${date +"%F"}_-${HOSTNAMEIP}-appserver0.log
>   ....

I am getting the following output in nagios:

*`could not find logfile /test/James-2018-11-16_-16.15.41.111-appserver0.log`*

**15215125111115** This number is always generated randomly but I don't know how to get nagios to identify it. Is there a way to add a variable for this or something? I tried adding an asterisk "*" but that didn't work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming; it may be better suited at https://serverfault.com/questions

Comment: Actually a bit of programming would easily solve this problem.  You need a 'wrapper' script to find the correct file (not enough details for selection here) and run check_logfiles with the correct file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
--tag failorder --type rotating::uniform --logfile /test/dummy \
--rotation "james-${date +"%F"}_\d+-${HOSTNAMEIP}-appserver0.log"
```

If you add a "-v" you can see what happens inside. Type rotating::uniform tells check_logfiles that the rotation scheme makes no difference between current log and rotated archives regarding the filename. (You frequently find something like xyz..log). What check_logfile does is to look into the directory where the logfiles are supposed to be. From /test/dummy it only uses the directory part. Then it takes all the files inside /test and compares the filenames with the --rotation argument. Those files which match are sorted by modification time. So check_logfiles knows which of the files in question was updated recently and the newest is considered to be the current logfile. And inside this file check_logfiles searches the criticalpattern. 
Gerhard